# Tracing the workings of a function in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I am learning emacs lisp.  One of the things I was playing with was setting variables.  So I go and set fill-column to 50 (setq fill-column 60).  After this evaluating fill-column does give me 60, but the function fill-paragraph ignores this.  How would I go about figuring out why this happens?

Thanks.

Best,
Bart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To instrument an Elisp function for debugging, load its source code, put point inside the function, and type `M-x edebug-defun`.  Then, when the function is executed, [the debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) will activate automatically.

In your particular case, `fill-column` becomes buffer local when set (see [make-variable-buffer-local](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Buffer_002dLocal.html#index-make_002dvariable_002dbuffer_002dlocal-623)).  You probably set it in the wrong buffer.

Comment: I run the code for setting the variable in the buffer I was running fill-paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could use debug-on-entry `^Hfdebug-on-entry`

```
debug-on-entry is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function.

(debug-on-entry FUNCTION)

Request FUNCTION to invoke debugger each time it is called.
```